# Disable making another TopLevel if it already exists

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I have an Instructions Window as`TopLevel` in my app. For now it looks like:

```
def instructions(self):     
    window = Toplevel(takefocus = True)
    window.geometry("200x200")
    window.resizable(0, 0)
    Label(window, text = "WIP").grid()
```

So it's part of the main class and I define a command to call when the user presses a button in the top menu or presses F3 a shortcut I defined.
What I need is when that window is once there I want it to take focus rather that opening a new one.

It could look like:

```
if window == exists:
    window.takefocus
else:
     do the upper and create it ....
```

also upon destruction in need to know that it hasbeen destoyed, otherwise I'll be able to open it only once

Comment: Define a variable `self.window=None` in `init`, and see if it's already there in `instructions`, and otherwise create a new window?

Comment: I had that idea but how do I check with an "if " that it alredy exists ?

Comment: Well, just check `if self.window is not None:`; the difficult part (which I just now don't know how best to approach) is how to un-set that variable when the window is closed.

Comment: Yes the unset variable was my concern too, I feared when at the end I set it to None, it would make the window dissapear. I need to somehow check that the window has been destroyed, then set the variable to none again

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
def instructions(self):        
    if self.window == None:
        self.window = Toplevel(takefocus = True)
        self.window.focus()
        self.window.geometry("200x200")
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        Label(self.window, text = "WIP").grid()
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.windowclosed)
    else:
        self.window.focus()       
def windowclosed(self):
    self.window.destroy()
    self.window = None
```